# How do I get at the goodies in my Grails Config.groovy at runtime?

Tags: configuration, grails, runtime

in Config.groovy I see this:

```
// set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}
```

what is the correct way to access that at runtime?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In more recent versions of grails ConfigurationHolder has been deprecated.

Instead you should use the grailsApplication object.

```
grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL
```

If in a Controller or Service then use dependency injection of grailsApplication object.
e.g.

```
class MyController{
    def grailsApplication
    def myAction() {
        grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL
    }
```

See [How to access Grails configuration in Grails 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133580/how-to-access-grails-configuration-in-grails-2-0)

Comment: Nice catch, ConfigurationHolder is deprecated in Grials 2.0 same as closures as "actions" :). http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/introduction.html#webFeatures

Comment: @khylo Isn't there also the possiblity of using the `grails.util.Holders` object, which is implemented since Grails 2.0 and use `Holders.config` to get read access to the `Config.groovy` file?

Comment: Yes.. thats true. .I didn't know about that class

Answer (score 31):

danb is on the right track.  However, life gets a bit easier on your fingers if you do a nicer import:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH
println CH.config.grails.serverURL
```

Comment: very nice.. i was completely unaware of that feature, which I will call import aliasing.

Comment: In grails 2.0 and above ConfigurationHolder (and other Holders) have been deprecated. Instead you should use dependency injection. See my answer below

Comment: Is there any other way to access the configuration in Util classes without Holder classes since there dependency injection is not possible?

Answer (score 14):

here it is:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
println ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.serverURL
```

alternatively, in controllers and tags, apparently this will work:

```
grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL
```

I needed it in BootStrap, so option 1 was what I needed.

Comment: This post explains it should still be possible to use option 2 (non-deprecated approach) in Bootstrap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133580/how-to-access-grails-configuration-in-grails-2-0

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in a few of the comments, another option is the [`grails.utils.Holders`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html) class which was added in Grails 2.0.  I prefer this approach since you can use it in classes that aren't configured with dependency injection.

```
import grails.util.Holders

class Foo {
    def bar() {
        println(Holders.config.grails.serverURL)
    }
}
```