# How to access config file kept in WEB-INF folder

Tags: tomcat, groovy, config

I am new to groovy. and looking for a way to store common configs at one place so my application can access it.

I am keeping configurations for my groovy applications in `WEB-INF`, how can I access the file from my main application?

I tried this `ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("config.groovy").toURL())`, but can't get it working, because the path where tomcat is expecting the `config.groovy` is where tomcat is installed. I have my appBase configured to some other location.

How do I give relative path to `new File('')` so that it can read the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this using the ClassLoader and not the filesystem directly. Basically, don't use `File`. I'm not sure how to do this in Groovy, but in plain-old Java it would look like this:

```
URL config = request.getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/config.groovy");
```

... then do whatever you want with the URL. (FYI the `getResource` method uses the ClassLoader of the webapp). So, maybe in Groovy that might be:

```
ConfigSlurper().parse(request.ServletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/config.groovy"))
```

Sorry I can't give you the exact Groovy syntax... not my world. :)

Comment: Thnx, I figured out, its `getClass().getResource("file")`.

Comment: It would be better to use the `ServletContext` since it will definitely give you the correct `ClassLoader`. `getClass()` will get you the `ClassLoader` of the servlet class which *should* be that of the context, but containers can play games with class loading and so obtaining the `ClassLoader` from the `ServletContext` is the safest bet.

Answer (score 1):

If your config must be set at deployment time, you can put the files in your war and access them with classloader.

For example, in a standard maven project, put your config files in src/main/resources/config/ directory (file1.config, file2.config. etc.). 
Then in your java code put the following

```
public class MyConfigLoader {

   void loadConfigFile(String configFileName) {
      InputStream is = MyConfigLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/"+configFileName);
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, isn't there any option by which I can just include the config once and use it in all groovy files? I mean without the need to create a function to read the file and use `ConfigSlurper`. Can't I just use the way `grails` provie configs? Somewhat like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/198541/1520671)

Answer (score 1):

For me this works every time

> Inject ‘grailsApplication’ in your BoosStrap, Controllers, TagLibs and
>   Services:

```
def grailsApplication
```

> Place your files in /web-app/WEB-INF/resources and use this line of
>   code to retrieve the directory of your resources:

```
def resources = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource('/WEB-INF/resources').file
```

> works both in development and production

Comment: Worked for Grails 3.0.9.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to move the configuration file from `WEB-INF` to the `grails-app/conf` folder. This folder is intended for the configuration files...

Grails allows you to easily import your custom config file by editing the `grails.config.locations` variable in `Config.groovy`. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized

If the name of your config file is `customConfig.groovy` and you moved it to  `grails-app/conf` you could use:

```
grails.config.locations = [ customConfig]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/config.groovy"))
```

this works for all environments.