# How to access config.groovy values in your controller?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have set login endpointUrl in config.groovy as

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = "/api/login"

How to access this endpointUrl values in your controller ?

Comment: select an answer

Answer (score 1):

In a controller you can use:

`Holders.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl`

Or:

`grailsApplication.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl`

See:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198365/how-do-i-get-at-the-goodies-in-my-grails-config-groovy-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm not a big fan of Holders because it makes your code a bit harder to test. Instead, I prefer to inject config to avoid having a dependency on the Holders class: 
`@Value('${grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl}')
 def endpointUrl`